# Create Prestashop theme using only PHP

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

i wondering if it's possible to create a full theme for prestashop using only PHP, without Smarty.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you not use Smarty?

Comment: Because i have to create a full new Prestashop web, with a really bizarre design, and i don't know anything about smarty, but i think i can do the design with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be possible. You can use PHP to read data from the Shop and render it without Smarty. But Smarty would make your life easier.

Just look at: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/122579-prestashop-without-using-smarty/